# PHP MySQL While Loop Is Only Returning The Last Row

Tags: php, mysql

I have been tasked with presenting a list of all photographs in relation to a photographer, when that photographer is clicked. I need to echo the list of photographs but currently, only the last row is being echoed.

The rows returned should look like this (minus the bullet points):

```
1 Amager Standpark Sunset 2010-07-01 _img/1/1.jpg 1
1 Field Landscape 2010-07-09 _img/1/2.jpg 1
```

However my code is only returning this:

```
1 Field Landscape 2010-07-09 _img/1/2.jpg 1
```

Below is my code:

```
            // SQL query to get all photo data from specific photographer
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Photograph WHERE PhotographerId='$photographerID'");
$photos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($num == 0) {
    echo 'This are no photographs present for this photographer.';
} else if ($num > 0) {

    $list = '';

    while ($photos = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

        $list .= $photos['PhotographerId'] . ' ' . $photos['PhotographName'] . ' ' .
                $photos['Date'] . ' ' . $photos['PhotographURL'] . ' ' .
                $photos['Visible'] . ' </br>';
    }

    echo $list;

}
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);` fetches the first row, then `mysqli_fetch_array($query)` fetches the subsequent rows within the loop. But you never use the first result set for anything. Also, make up your mind which kind of array you want!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` right after you run your query effectively using the first set of results. Then once you start  your loop you start t=at the second row.

Removing it will solve your issue and make the first result set available to your loop.

You can also just use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()` inside of your loop. `mysqli_fetch_array()` returns both the associative and numerically indexed results of your query which you don't need.

```
// SQL query to get all photo data from specific photographer
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Photograph WHERE PhotographerId='$photographerID'");
$num = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($num == 0) {
    echo 'This are no photographs present for this photographer.';
} else if ($num > 0) {

    $list = '';

    while ($photos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        $list .= $photos['PhotographerId'] . ' ' . $photos['PhotographName'] . ' ' .
                $photos['Date'] . ' ' . $photos['PhotographURL'] . ' ' .
                $photos['Visible'] . ' </br>';
    }

    echo $list;

}
```

I don't know where you get `$photographerID` from but if it is user input this code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attacks](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to avoid this risk.